# RabbitMQ прослушивание одной очереди с разных консюмеров

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Есть продюсер:

```
@Configuration
public class ToDoConfig {

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        template.setExchange("my_topic_exchange");
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queueCreation(@Value("${todo.amqp.queue}") String queue) {
        return new Queue(queue, true, false, false);
    }

}

@Component
@Log4j2
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ToDoProducer {
    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void sendTo(String key, ToDo toDo)  {
        log.info("попытка отправить инфу");
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(key, toDo);
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
@Service
public class ScheduledBaySend {
    private final ToDoProducer toDoProducer;
    private final Environment environment;
    private static Integer k  = 0;
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000L)
    public void send() {
        toDoProducer.sendTo(this.environment.getProperty("todo.amqp.key"), new TodoBuilder()
                .setName("mname " + k++)
                .setDesc("desc").build());
    }
}
```

и есть консюмер в том же приложении:

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class ToDoConsumer {
private final ToDoRepository toDoRepository;

    public ToDoConsumer(ToDoRepository toDoRepository) {
        this.toDoRepository = toDoRepository;
    }


    @RabbitListener(queues = "${todo.amqp.queue}")
    public void processTodo(ToDo message) {
        log.info("Consumer >> {}", message);
        this.toDoRepository.save(message);
        log.info("Save todo >> {}", message);
    }
}
```

провперти

```
# ключ по которому отправляется сообщение в топик
todo.amqp.key=my_key
# первая очередь которая забиндилась получать по ключу сообщение из топика
todo.amqp.queue=spring=boot
```

и вот я хочу чтобы очередь слушалась и со второго приложения но чтобы данные из одной очереди отдавались
в два приложения т.е. если я отправил сообщение то оно должно отобразиться и в первом и во втором консюмере. конечно я могу в rabbitMQ  создать ещё одну очередь например spring=boot2 и забиндиться на exchange и во втором приложении подписаться уже на вторую очередь а не на первую...

[image]

и данные тоже будут поступать равномерно

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class ToDoConsumer {
private final ToDoRepository toDoRepository;

    public ToDoConsumer(ToDoRepository toDoRepository) {
        this.toDoRepository = toDoRepository;
    }


    @RabbitListener(queues = "spring=boot2")
    public void processTodo(ToDo message) {
        log.info("Consumer >> {}", message);
        this.toDoRepository.save(message);
        log.info("Save todo >> {}", message);
    }

}
```

а получится ли получать равномерно данные из одной очереди , установив время  жизни сообщения и указав что это консюмер уже другой.????

Answer (score 2):

Невозможно из одной очереди одно сообщение получить сразу нескольким консьюмерам, для каждого консьюмера нужно сделать свою очередь, иначе консьюмеры будут по очереди разбирать сообщения.

Создайте 2 очереди, сделайте для них одинаковый биндинг:

```
channel.queueDeclare("spring-boot", false, false, false, null);
channel.queueDeclare("spring-boot2", false, false, false, null);
channel.queueBind("spring-boot", "exchange", "spring", null);
channel.queueBind("spring-boot2", "exchange", "spring", null);
```

И отправляем:

```
channel.basicPublish("exchange", "spring", null, message.getBytes());
```

Как на спринге это реализовывается я не подскажу, но надеюсь смысл передал))

Comment: спасибо, как это сделать я знаю, интересовал вопрос можно ли получать из одной очереди двум консюмерам. раз нельзя значит всё понятно.

Comment: @Alex Mur если ответ помог, примите его как правильный.